# Javascript to change text shadow direction at a certain time

Tags: javascript, css, time, shadow

I am trying to use javascript to change the direction of a text shadow between 9 and 10pm.

Have tried a number of alterations and not sure where I am going wrong, here are the basics of my code..

```
<head>

<style>

 body {
    text-shadow: 12px 12px 8px #000000;
}

</style>

<script>

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

if (21 <= currentTime && currentTime < 22) 
{
document.getElementById('body').text.style.textShadow  = "-12px 12px 8px 
#000000";
}

</script>

</head>
```

.. haven't included the body, but my text is within < div class="..." > , and < a href="..." > if this helps ?

So normally the text shadow should be to the right, and between 9 and 10pm should be to the left?

Thanks!

Comment: ....what is  document.getElementById('body') ?

Comment: how should I word it ? I'm trying to piece it together from what I've used previously.

Comment: Where is your html that the style and script are referring to?

Comment: @joehigh1, you might want to use `document.body` directly instead of ` document.getElementById('body')`, unless you have an element with ` id="body" `? Is your intention to change the shadow of the whole document?

Comment: hey , no no just of all text (but none of it is between <p> quotes)

Comment: @solarc , so I should be able to use .. document.body.text.style.textShadow  = "-12px 12px 8px #000000";  ??

Answer (score 0):

As per comment I assume this is wrong:

```
document.getElementById('body').text
```

A sample snippet to clarify:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      document.querySelectorAll('div, a').forEach(function(ele) {
         ele.style.textShadow  = "-12px 12px 8px #000000";
      });
  })

});
```

```css
body {
    text-shadow: 12px 12px 8px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div>
    this is a text iside a div......
</div>
<a href="">this is a text inside an anchor......</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry it would have helped to put this in the question, my text isn't between <p> , but are within <div class="..."> , or <a href="..."> if this helps?

Comment: I'm struggling to integrate this into the site I am working on, here is the page, if you view the full code to have an idea of whats going on.. http://sarahboulton.co.uk/chapelbedroom.html

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('div[class*=deadsaints-]').forEach(function(ele) {ele.style.textShadow  = "-12px 12px 8px #000000";});

Comment: Hi, does this still require the function(e) of a button being clicked ? It doesn't seem to be working within the time based javascript i am using?

Comment: you changed class names. Now you need to use: document.querySelectorAll('div[class*=basilswan]')....